# Wakanda reporting and data extract options

Tags: javascript, reporting, wakanda

I am finishing up a new app in Wakanda and need a decent reporting tool for some canned reports.  Basic tabular, subtotal and formatted reports with the ability to export as txt or xls (pdf would be nice as well).  Other than the compute method and a couple of basic graphs, I am not seeing many options in the doc and no standard methods for clean extract of data that I can find.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Bring some code so that we can help you. Otherwise this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [repository](https://github.com/hamzahik/wakanda-reporting-example) with a simple reporting sample using Wakanda. Your HTML file should use underscore [templating syntax](http://underscorejs.org/#template).

Comment: I think this is something I can work with.  Thanks.  I will circle back with a sample of what I end up with.